# IntelliJ 12 on OSX 10.8.2 Mt Lion with Java 7

Tags: java, intellij-idea, osx-mountain-lion

Problem: running IntelliJ 12 on OSX 10.8.2 with Java 7.

I have a fresh OSX 10.8.2 Mt Lion install, and I've installed the official Oracle Java 7 (no Java 6 present).

I've installed the latest version (12.0.1) of IntelliJ IDEA, and edited /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 12 CE.app/Contents/Info.plist to have JVMVersion like so:

```
JVMVersion
1.7*
```

When I try to start up IDEA (or when I run ./Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 12\ CE.app/Contents/MacOS/idea) I get "No Java runtime present, requesting install." and a popup window saying "To open “IntelliJ IDEA,” you need a Java SE 6 runtime. Would you like to install one now?". I chose "Not Now".

I do have Java 7, but it seems that for some reason IDEA can't see it.

```
>java -version
java version "1.7.0_12-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_12-ea-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b28, mixed mode)
```

My .profile file has

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Some terminal output:

```
>echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_12.jdk/Contents/Home

>echo $PATH
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_12.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
```

In my System Preferences > Java, there is a single entry; Java 7 (1.7.0_12-ea).

So, what little silly thing am I missing? :)

Comment: Change JVMVersion to 1.6* in Info.plist.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019199/how-do-i-run-idea-intellij-on-mac-os-x-with-jdk-7

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK it not yet possible to run idea on jdk 7. See [this](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5472169#5472169) discussion where the [reason](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93710) is also explained.

Comment: Thanks :) I shall keep digging around for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround as I posted on the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19621573/165835, for those are OCDs that can't have two JDK on their machines..

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to add some fields to this file: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.**.jdk/Contents/`

```
<key>JVMCapabilities</key>
<array>
<string>CommandLine</string>
<string>JNI</string>
<string>BundledApp</string>
<string>WebStart</string>
<string>Applets</string> 
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem to what you explained here in your question.

The solution that fixed my problem was as follows:

In:

> Project Settings > Compiler > Java Compiler

I changed the drop down `Use compiler` from `Javac` to `Eclipse`!

Non of the other solutions I found on the web was helpful. Hope this helps you my unknown fellow reader.

> IMPORTANT: THIS HAD NOTHING TO DO WITH MY JAVA_HOME AS IT WAS SET CORRECTLY.