# Open Java applications fail silently on OS X Mavericks

Tags: java, intellij-idea, android-studio, osx-mavericks

When opening Intelli J or Android Studio after the Mavericks update nothing happens, fails silently.

Java and javac all work from the command line.

Opening the apps from the command line gives this error:
`LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10658 for the file /Applications/Android Studio.app.`

Opening Intelli J's `idea_appLauncher` (/Applications/...app/Contents/MacOS/idea_appLauncher) from the command line gave away some more information:

> someuser@machine:~$ /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 12\
>   CE.app/Contents/MacOS/idea_appLauncher ; exit; No Java runtime
>   present, requesting install. logout
>
> [Process completed]

Obviosuly Mavericks is not picking up on my Java installation even if it's part of PATH and JAVA_HOME is set and it's not giving the "Please install Java runtime" prompt.

Comment: I encounter the same problem after installing java and intellij using "brew cask". Pity, I really fancy command-line install over manual.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution:

Download and install the [Java Runtime](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) manually.

You also need to enable application from all sources from Settings/Security & Privacy.

Answer (score 14):

In my case I saw a similar error but with different error code:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE.app with error -10810.
```

*This worked for me:* just edit the file `/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 13\ CE.app/Contents/Info.plist` and change the key field `JVMVersion` from `1.6*` to `1.7*`.

My stack:

- IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE
- java version "1.7.0_51"
- OS X 10.9.1

Comment: This solved the situation when installing both java and intellij using "brew cask"

Answer (score 5):

This is due to android studio/intellij is still using the old "JavaLaunching" framework which has deprecated with Java 7. Either you install an End-Of-Life version of JDK 6, or request Android Studio to upgrade to use oracle's JDK appbundle.

I really hate to install a JAVA 6 so I'll have two JDKs on my machine. so I hacked the Android studio files such that they can be launched from the dock:

1. Change the studio (in `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS`) file from a JavaLauncher stub to a shell script, here's how it look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
echo JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME
export APP_PACKAGE='/Applications/Android Studio.app'
exec $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp $JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:"$APP_PACKAGE"/lib/bootstrap.jar:"$APP_PACKAGE"/lib/extensions.jar:"$APP_PACKAGE"/lib/util.jar:"$APP_PACKAGE"/lib/jdom.jar:"$APP_PACKAGE"/lib/log4j.jar:"$APP_PACKAGE"/lib/trove4j.jar:"$APP_PACKAGE"/lib/jna.jar -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudioPreview -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xverify:none -Xbootclasspath/a:"$APP_PACKAGE"/lib/boot.jar -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xdock:icon="$APP_PACKAGE"/Contents/Resources/AndroidStudio.icns com.intellij.idea.Main
```

make sure to `chmod +x ./studio` to it.

1. Remove the java section in the Info.plist file in the `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents` directory. Otherwise, Apple will still ask you to install JDK 6: edit the file and remove the whole java section. The diff will look like: http://pastebin.com/QS8M45cr

Answer (score 2):

I had java 1.7 but none of the above worked or matched my problem log. Starting Android Studio silently failed. I reverted to java 1.6, same behaviour and both had the same error log (see below).

My error log showed:

```
android studio taskgated failed to get signing info for  (cannot make code: invalid signature (code or signature have been modified))
```

Most answers on StackOverflow to that particular error log is that you have to "Allow applications downloaded from anywhere" in Security & Privacy.

Then I saw what @jmcejuela did and that worked quite well and I edited

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

and changed

```
1.6*
```

to

```
1.7*
```

My environment:

- Android Studio 0.4.2
- java version "1.7.0_45"
- OSX Version 10.8.5

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I saw an `"Allow it anyway"` option for Android Studio under `Settings->Security&Privacy->General Tab`. When I click it, it removed the restriction for Android Studio.