# Opening .app on Mac OS X 10.8.5 results in error -10658

Tags: java, macos, .app

I have Wrapped a `.jar` in an `.app` and tried opening it on `Mac 10.8.5`
But i get the following error

```
2014-08-05 18:09:12.067 open[20857:707] JLRequestRuntimeInstall: CFMessagePortSendRequest: error -1
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10658 for the file /Users/ib-mac-1/Desktop/myapp.app.
```

The same `.app` file works fine on `10.7.5` and `10.9`

Can anyone throw some light on this error ? tried googling but no luck

**EDIT : This should work For most of you facing the above problem** [Open Java applications fail silently on OS X Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594627/open-java-applications-fail-silently-on-os-x-mavericks)

Comment: Have you seen http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81330/downloaded-apps-does-not-start-error-10658 ?. It might be permission problem. Try `chmod +x`.

Comment: no, its not a permission issue :)

Comment: This solved my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594627/open-java-applications-fail-silently-on-os-x-mavericks

Comment: Strange issue. It may have been because of recent Java update that I made, or it could be something else. It was working a few hours ago. Anyway, I just replaced the previous .app with the new one (extracted from .zip).