# Can not open Android studio on Sierra OS

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, homebrew-cask

All of sudden my Android studio is not working. When I am trying to open it, I get this window.
[image: Error dialog window]

I tried to luanch from command line using this command:

```
 /> open Android\ Studio.app
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/Android Studio.app.
```

But I still get this error.
I have tried to uninstall and reinstall `android-studio` several times using `brew cask`. But everytime I get the same error.

I searched on internet, some people got this error when JVM is not installed correctly. I recheck the my JVM configuration and looks fine.
I am not able to figure out what is wrong. I think I am missing something which I am not able to figure out.

Comment: This question is for when mavericks came out. Have you tried it yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594627/open-java-applications-fail-silently-on-os-x-mavericks?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: did you try to install it without brew? (out of curiosity, why do you use brew for this?)

Comment: @th3pat3l I tried that already but it didn't work.

Comment: @njzk2 I didn't try installing it without brew. I use brew mostly for package management. This way it is easier to remove the package and reinstall.

Comment: I used appCleaner to remove all the files related with Android studio and reinstall the androidStudio again and it worked.