# Don't run Android Studio 4.0.1

Tags: android-studio

I install Android Studio about 2 week ago and all work fine. But today I  run studio and it don't start. I remove and install again. But it also don't work.

```
open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Android Studio.app with error -10810.
```

macOS Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594627/open-java-applications-fail-silently-on-os-x-mavericks except it's from far older OS

Comment: I see this article and try doing. but it don't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted folder /Users/user/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio4.0
And run app. App run and work correct.