# Run java application for HDPI screen?

Tags: java, hdpi

Is there a way to run a java application for HDPI screen? ( like any console option )

Or HDPI is required to be addressed by code?

Context:

We have an application which is unusable in HDPI screens due to the size of text and icons. If not possible through options, we would have to implement some interface change in the code, but that would require more time.

Comment: this sounds highly unusual - is this for an Android application? If so, have you checked whether it runs out of memory ?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos: It does not run out of memory. It is unusable because normal ~12px-14px letters on a 15'' 3840x2160 screen look so small that you would require a magnifying glass to read. Actually it does not matter whenever is for Android or not (that is the good point of Java).

Comment: Ah, sorry - I read it as "unstable" for some reason. Still, I mention Android because it has built-in display-independent pixels as measurement (dp) that helps with exactly this issue. Since I'm assuming you're probably running it on an Apple device, [other people had similar issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181079/apple-retina-display-support-in-java-jdk-1-7-for-awt-swing)

Comment: To answer your question, the user report comes comes from a Linux/KDE 15.6'' 4K touchscreen laptop Asus. Android is also Unix-based, but it's solutions are probably not applicable.