# How to change JRE for PhpStorm on MacOs

Tags: macos, phpstorm

It seems, with the latest MAcOs updates, that Java was also updated, which influenced PhpStorm performance very badly.

Anyway, I decided to update my Java.

Was

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-457-11M4509)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-457, mixed mode)
```

After downloading Java SDK from Oracle and installing:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

But in PhpStorm it still shows the old JRE:
[image: old jre]

I also restarted my computer, but still the old JRE is shown.

Please help, how to make PHPStorm use a new JRE?

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from the ["Selecting the JDK version the IDE will run under" article](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956) in the [Knowledge Base](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/)
<sub>posted on March 27, 2013</sub>

> ### Mac OS X
>
> At the moment all our products require **Apple JDK 1.6** to be installed in order to run on Mac. JDK 1.7 from Oracle is not officially supported yet and has known problems that stop us from using it by default. Oracle **JDK 1.7.0_40** has added support for Retina and works much better than previous versions on Mac. You are welcome to give it a try in case you have any problems with Apple JDK.
>
> To force running under JDK 1.7 edit **/Applications/.app/Contents/Info.plist** file, change JVMVersion from **1.6*** to **1.7*** :
>
> ```
> <key>JVMVersion</key>
> <string>1.7*</string>
> ```
>
> - [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13019403/104891) for the known problems with JDK 1.7.
> - **IDEA_JDK** environment variable can be used to override the selected JDK, you may need to run the product from the Terminal so that it sees your environment variables (Mac OS limitation): **open -a /Applications/.app/** .
> - Application **About** dialog will show the actual JDK version.

Comment: Now you will have to monitor this document for any changes and update your answer for the end of time, or other users will downvote it when it becomes obsolete, just like you did for my answer.

Comment: Not really, when this answer becomes incorrect *any* user can update it accordingly, as there is a source to quote from.
Also, let's hope user downvote answers that are incorrect or obsolete, 
there wouldn't be much use for StackOverflow otherwise ;-)

Comment: +1 on answer and your above comment: thanks for quoting the solution here. The same content in the link has been superseded by instructions for later versions. Your posting of the (now earlier) version of the content here was very helpful to me - it enabled me to get an earlier PHPStorm running in order to then do an upgrade. At the time I wasn't sure whether could just download the newer version or upgrade so having your information gave me the option. Thanks!